# Updating thousands of rows in oracle using executeBatch with spring jdbc

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to execute bunch of UPDATE statements using spring jdbc template through executeBatch, some of these UPDATE queries may update thousands of records in the database. But, during the execution of these queries, it seems that the transaction is getting timeout. How to enforce spring jdbc template to run the statement until it completes all the updates? I have the following configuration for spring jdbc template, but still I get the following error.

> SQL state [null]; error code [17081]; error occurred during batching:
>   ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation ; nested
>   exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: error occurred during
>   batching: ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation

```
this.jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(ds);
jdbc.setFetchSize(1000);
jdbc.setQueryTimeout(0); // zero means there is no limit
```

I have also tried with **jdbc.setQueryTimeout(600000);** which also did not work.